# Is it better to sort an array and then use the binary search, or use the naive solution directly?

Tags: arrays, sorting

Why it is better to sort an array and then use the binary search?
Can't we just use the naive solution directly?

Comment: What's "*the* naive solution"? Looping through the array to look for a value?

Comment: yes, looping through an array!

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to look for an item once or twice and your array is not already sorted, then there's no point in sorting it and using binary search.

Sorting and then using binary search is more efficient if you need to search the same array multiple times. Sorting it once and then using binary search results in doing some extra work in the beginning to make subsequent searches faster. (Finding out the break point is left as an exercise for the reader)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is finding an item in an array. The naive solution, iterating over the array, has a complexity of O(n).

Sorting an array is an O(nlog(n)) operation, so even without the binary search it would be (theoretically) slower than just iterating the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
Why it is better to sort an array and then use the binary search?
```

Your statement right there isn't always true.

It **is** better if you need to search for items in either a very large array, or just very frequently. Or  both.

If you need to access an item in an array of size 5 only a couple of times, just iterate through it without any concern.

Sorting **IS** a big task. If you can define how long it would take and measure to the computing time you would save by sorting beforehand, then you got your answer. Usually I wouldn't care much for the exact time gained, I just know if that array is gonna be used 3 times or 300 times, and most of the times the answer doesn't need to be calculated.

Afterwards, iterating vs binary search is literally half the computing time.